# Run Single node Cassandra cluster and do queries with QUORUM consistency?

Tags: cassandra, cql, consistency

I'm trying to setup a simple and "lightweight" development/testing environment for my application where I could run single node Cassandra cluster with key space where `'replication_factor':'1'`.

But when I do CQL query with QUORUM consistecy then I still get an error for not having two nodes in my cluster:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: 
Not enough replica available for query at consistency QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)
```

Any way to allow queries to work with QUORUM consistency level in this one node setup or is only fallback to use ONE (or add second node to cluster)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have changed it to a replication_factor of 2 or 3 by mistake; QUORUM of 1 is 1.